# Setting the colour of a dynamically created tile does not work

Tags: unity, c#, tilemap

I have a function that takes in the position of a tile on a Tilemap and sets the colour. If I do not replace the tile with a dynamically created one, it works just fine.

However, if I create a tile at runtime, set it's colour and add it to the tilemap, the tile does not change. In the preview window it appears black.

The function can be found below:

```
private void CreateTile(Vector3Int tilePosition)
{
    var tempTile = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<Tile>();

    tempTile.flags = TileFlags.None;
    tempTile.color = Color.green;

    tilemap.SetTile(tilePosition, tempTile);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, I have spent a few hours on this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the 2D render pipeline by any chance? (Any chance you just forgot to add lights to the scene?)

Comment: @qwyxivi There is a 2D render pipeline? [All I can find in the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/render-pipelines.html) are the Standard pipeline, the HDRP and the URP. The URP is recommended for 2D and has a couple 2D-only goodies like 2D lights, but it can just as well be used for 3D rendering.

Comment: @Philipp My bad, I meant the 2D rendering configuration of URP.